# Help with designing a form

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to use a TreeView and design a form similar to the following image:

[image]

Details:

- user select item group from treeview (treeview content checkbox).
- After check each group from treeview items in this group fetch from SqlServer DB and show in the ListBox and when unchecked remove items from ListBox.

What is the best way to design this form?

Comment: Sounds like you have it designed already.

Comment: I have no idea what @Letseatlunch is talking about. Nothing that @yodaj007 said was rude or offensive. It *does* appear that you have already designed the *layout* of the form; now it's a simple matter of dragging the controls to the appropriate locations in the Designer. I'm not sure what the question is here...

Comment: @Cody: Me neither.  I wasn't intending to cause any controversy.  I'm not sure what "ramming a green puppet" means.  Not sure I want to know.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have hierarchy in the data?

If not it would be better to have both listboxes one listbox displaying the all available data and the other displaying the subscribed / added data.

You could also put two buttons one "Add" and another "Remove" at the center (between the listboxes). `"Add"` would move the data from `"Available List"` to `"Added List"` and `"Remove"` would remove the data from `"Added List"` and add it to the `"Available List"`.

Comment: Yes items groups have hierarchy (parents and childs) . items may be Very much and show all of them in the listbox not good . Do you have better way? Thanks

Comment: If that is the case, your design works provided you can uniquely map each list item to the tree node. (There could be two nodes with a same name under different parents.)